# Can't draw text on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I'm just starting out JS with some previous programming knowledge from other languages. I've been trying to learn more JS by making a canvas that can render text.

https://jsfiddle.net/b5n2rypn/

**The problem:**
The code above calls fillText but no text is rendered. It was working before I created the class `RichText` and started trying to draw using its methods. Didn't find any errors on console and I can't seem figure out what the issue is.

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.DOMText.style.width` returns string not integer (eg. "128px") and then if you multiply it by ratio it will return NaN which is probably converted to 0. you would need to parseInt on **w** and **h** in your `createCanvas` function because now your canvases are 0x0 dimensions.

```
function createCanvas(w, h, ratio) {
        w = parseInt(w);
        h = parseInt(h);

        ...
```